# StatementInvalid SQLite3::SQLException: no such column. When adding a tagging system to a blog

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tagging

So I decided to build a tagging system in my RoR blog. After following the Getting Started Official rails guide, im following up with one from jumpstartlabs http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/projects/blogger.html#i3:-tagging
Where I'm basically using the 'join table' method to map the Many Posts Have Many Tags and Many Tags Have Many Posts relationship

This is the error I'm getting

```
  ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Posts#show
  Showing /home/nadia/blog/app/views/posts/show.html.erb where line #8 raised:

  SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: taggings.post_id: SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags"                INNER JOIN "taggings" ON "tags"."id" = "taggings"."tag_id" WHERE "taggings"."post_id" = ?
   Extracted source (around line #8):


6   <p>
7     Tags:
8     <% @post.tags.each do |tag| %>
9         <%= link_to tag.name, tag_path(tag) %>
10     <% end %>
11     </p>
```

this is my tags_controller

```
 1 class TagsController < ApplicationController
 2
 3     def show
 4       @tag = Tag.find(params[:id])
 5     end
 6 end
```

post_controller

```
1 class PostsController < ApplicationController
2   include PostsHelper
3   http_basic_authenticate_with name: "Nadia", password: "possum", except: [:index, :show]
4
5   def index
6     @posts = Post.all
7   end
8
9   def show
10     @post = Post.find(params[:id])
11   end
12
13   def edit
14     @post = Post.find(params[:id])
15   end
16
17   def update
18     @post = Post.find(params[:id])
19
20         if @post.update(post_params)
21             redirect_to action: :show, id: @post.id
22         else
23             render 'edit'
24         end
25   end
26    def new
27       @post = Post.new
28    end
29    def create
30       @post = Post.new(post_params)
31
32         if @post.save
33             redirect_to action: :show, id: @post.id
34          else
35             render 'new'
36          end
37    end
38
39    def destroy
40        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
41        @post.destroy
42
43     redirect_to action: :index
44     end
45
46     private
47
48     def post_params
49         params.require(:post).permit(:title, :text,)
50
51      end
52 end
```

model: post.rb

```
   1 class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
   2 
   3     has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
   4     has_many :taggings
   5     has_many :tags, through: :taggings
   6     validates :title,
   7             presence: true,
   8                length: { minimum: 5 }
   9 
   10   def tag_list
   11     self.tags.collect do |tag|
   12       tag.name
   13   end.join(", ")
   14 end
   15   def tag_list=(tags_string)
   16     tag_names = tags_string.split(",").collect{|s| s.strip.downcase}.uniq
   17     new_or_found_tags = tag_names.collect { |name| Tag.find_or_create_by(name:     name) }
   18     self.tags = new_or_found_tags
   19   end
   20 end
```

model: tag.rb

```
1 class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
2   has_many :taggings
3   has_many :posts, through: :taggings
4 end
```

and last but not least my posts_helpers.rb

```
1 module PostsHelper
2   def post_params
3     params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, :tag_list)
4   end
5 end
```

Please let me know if you would like to see any other files. I would love some help as this is my first real project. :)

Edit. My Taggings.rb

```
1 class Tagging < ActiveRecord::Base
2   belongs_to :tag
3   belongs_to :post
4 end
```

Comment: Your `@post` probably returns a `nil` `tag_list`. Why use a text field for that? (remember `@post.tag_list` will be called). Check http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/text_field)

Comment: To be very honest with you I followed the instructions, and they weren't very clear on why you do that. And my knowledge at this point in time isn't advance enough to understand why either.

Comment: `SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: taggings.post_id` says exactly what's wrong. Your taggings model should have a `post_id` and `tag_id` to properly reference the many-to-many relation. What does your schema say? (I don't understand my previous comment, I guess you edited the error).

Comment: Oh I see. I assumed that by saying that Tagging belongs_to :tag and :post that, that would give me the foreign keys I need to connect the tables? Or is this something I do manually by defining a change method in the migration?

Answer (score 6):

I found a typo/pluralization in the Taggings.rb file.

```
 belongs_to :posts
```

which I then changed to

```
 belongs_to :post
```

However the important part was I forgot I had to re run the migration to re-name the name of the column. I checked the column names by running

```
 Tagging.column_names
```

to find that the column was in fact named wrong: posts_id

after running

```
 rake db:migrate
```

with the fixed Tagging.rb file it fixed the problem by re-naming that column.

Thank you so much every one
I really appreciate the help. Learned a bunch over the last few days trying to fix this small problem.

Comment: +1 For caring enough to answer yourself. Be sure to accept it tough.